# Asignar a un Array resultado de ArrayList() Java

Tags: java, array

El método `toArray` de la clase `ArrayList` retorna un array de objetos.¿Como se puede hacer para que retorne un array de cadenas (StringList[])?
¿Se debe hacer así?

```
ArrayList<String> nombreArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: ¿Lo has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que todo el método `toArray();` te va a devolver un Array que contenga elementos del mismo tipo que el ArrayList.

Aquí está la definición del método, en donde T es el tipo que contiene y devuelve el método.

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona.

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList.add("Juan");
arrList.add("Pedro");
arrList.add("Pablo");
arrList.add("Mateo");
arrList.add("Marcos");

//tienes un ArrayList, ahora tienes que declarar un Array del mismo tipo

String arr[] = new String[arrList.size()];
arr = arrList.toArray(arr);
```

Postada: el String con la "S" en mayúscula, pues es la clase envoltorio de string en con "s" minúscula.

Answer (score 2):

Existe un método para que retorne un arreglo del tipo de datos que buscas, tal como se indica en [`List#toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-). El ejemplo sería así:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "world"));
String[] arreglo = lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()]);
System.out.println(lista);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglo));
```