# pasar arraylist a Arreglo

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Estoy tratando de pasar los valores de un `arraylist` a un arreglo pero me dice que todos los registros son `null`.

```
public static void listadedatos() {

for(int i = 0; i < datostabla2.size(); i++) {
    datostabla[i] = (String) datostabla2.get(i);//------------- trato de copiarlo de esta forma y no sirve
    //System.arraycopy(datostabla2, 0, datostabla, 0, datostabla2.size());// trato de copiarloo de esta forma y tampoco sirve 
    //System.out.println("Valor array= " + datostabla2.get(i));
}
for(int i = 0; i < datostabla.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Valor arreglo= " + datostabla[i]);
}

}
  public static void listadedatos2() {


    try {
        datostabla2.add(result.getObject(i+1));
        for(int i = 0; i < datostabla2.size(); i++) {
            datostabla[i] = (String) datostabla2.get(i);
            //System.out.println("Valor antes= " + datostabla2.get(i));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Asignar a un Array resultado de ArrayList() Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31145/asignar-a-un-array-resultado-de-arraylist-java)

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar un `ArrayList<String>` a un array (`String[]`) la propia clase `ArrayList` te proporciona [las herramientas necesarias](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-):

```
String [] arrayDeStrings = miArrayList.toArray(new String[miArrayList.size()]);
```

Por cierto, si usas genéricos (es lo recomendable), no necesitarás hacer un casting de los elementos. En el ejemplo que te doy asumo que miArrayList fue declarada así:

```
ArrayList<String> miArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Lo que te permitiría sacar cualquier elemento así:

```
String elem = miArrayList.get(n);
```